# Why can't I inspect local variables with IntelliTrace for VS 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

When navigating to previous calls/events during debugging with IntelliTrace, I can't see a snapshot of the value of locally-defined variables.  When hovering with the mouse I get the message "Intellitrace data has not been collected".  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Intellitrace team covered this a bit in one of their blog entries.  Here is the link (it's in the comment section)

- http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2009/11/16/intellitrace-itrace-files.aspx

The short version though is that collecting all local variables was too much of a performance hit.  Instead they only selectively capture locals.  That is they will collect locals which

- Are evaluated in the debugger during the debugging session
- Values which have trace points defined against them
- Local variables which are specifically configured to be captured (didn't go into detail on how to do that other than setting up a trace point).

Comment: Thanks, JaredPar.  That makes sense.  Digging deeper into the MSDN documentation, I noticed they allude to this somewhat.  However, they emphasize what *is* collected over what is not.

Answer (score 4):

Note that a later blog post from the same blogger - http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2010/03/16/intellitrace-what-we-collect.aspx - expanded quite on the limitations and how you can get around them somewhat.